# Enable Terminal / iterm2 sound notification exclusively

Tags: macos, terminal, notifications

Is there a way to enable the bell terminal and other sound notification from the terminal, while my "play user interface sound effect" setting is off ?

I don't like to have any sound notification (I prefer the flashing screen), but I'm using weechat and I wish I could enable some sound notification in it.

Answer (score 14):

You can create separate profiles one with sound disabled (default) and one with sound enabled (for your `weechat`). These are available both in Terminal and iTerm2.

**Terminal**
[image]

**iTerm2**

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer and to took the time to take screenshot.

maybe I should have been clearer : in System Preferences / Sound / Sound effect , I disabled the "Play user interface sound effects", cause I don't want any sound from the U. So what I'm looking for is a solution to overwrite this setting just for the terminal/iterm2

maybe there is a way with a command line.

Comment: For me that `Play user interface sound effects` settings doesn't have any effect on terminal bell sound (El Capitan 10.11.1)

Comment: you are correct. I stand corrected - my alert volume was all the way down. sorry and thanks for your help

Comment: but now, I wish I could get the alert for the terminal exclusively. any idea ?

Comment: It disables sounds like dragging items to trash, but for sounds inside terminal the profile settings takes preference. Do you hear a bell in terminal window on pressing say F10 with `Play user interface sound effects` disabled but `Audible Bell` enabled?

Comment: yes. just need to rise the `alert volume` a bit. do you have any idea how I could enable the alert sound just for the terminal ?

Comment: With `Play user interface sound effects` disabled but `Audible Bell` in your terminal profile preferences enabled, you should be able to get what you are looking for (see screenshot).