# Why isn't my system producing an audible system beep in iTerm2 or Terminal?

Tags: terminal, macos, audio, iterm, alert

I want to be able to hear the system beep. Normally, this can be done by running any of the following commands in OSX:

- `echo -e "\a"`
- `printf "\a"`
- `tput bel`

Running these commands in the standard `Terminal` app (Version 2.6.1 [361.1]) produces no visible or audible effect.

Running these commands in the `iTerm2` app (Build 3.0.15) produces a small, golden bell next to the tab name at the top of the window, but produces no sound. If I enable the "Flash visual bell" setting, I get the small, golden bell *plus* a larger bell icon over the whole terminal window, as shown here:

[image: screenshot of terminal window showing visual bell]

The profile I use has what appear to be the correct settings: 
[image: iTerm2 Profile settings screenshot]

For comparison, `say "hello world"` makes the computer speak "hello world" audibly -- my speakers are not muted.

Note that [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/214513/enable-terminal-iterm2-sound-notification-exclusively) is similar, but asks for the special case of enabling sound in certain situations but not others.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that I hadn't selected an alert sound yet in System Preferences. Once I chose an alert sound, all three of the above methods produced audible system beeps, in additiona

To enable audio alerts, I chose an alert sound from the Sound tab of the System Preferences:

[image: Screenshot of the Sound tab of System Preferences]

I chose "Sosumi" out of nostalgia for my [IIci](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwigqeCms83VAhUIjFQKHWIADpIQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FMacintosh_IIci&usg=AFQjCNHc-np65fvrZqTh7qO6m3KIGtkhkg) days.

Alternatively, this can be set as described in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/114430/71317), though iTerm2 needs to be restarted for it to take effect in *Sierra* or *El Capitan*:

```
defaults write com.apple.systemsound com.apple.sound.beep.sound /System/Library/Sounds/Sosumi.aiff
```